# Can Anyone Recommend a Good Book on Quaternions?

Tags: reference-request, matrix-equations, book-recommendation, quaternions

Although I have used them at work, I don't understand quaternions. How were they discovered intuitively? How do they work? Can anyone recommend a good book on quaternions?

Comment: Check out [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion)

Comment: See the references [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Quaternion.html), and perhaps Pertti Lounesto's book [**Clifford Algebras and Spinors**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0511526024/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the question "How were they discovered intuitively ?" and "How do they work ?", you may read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#History).

For understanding the subject, you may also follow

$1.~~$ "A Primer of Quaternions" by Arthur Stafford Hathaway

$2.~~$ "Quaternions and Rotation Sequences – A Primer with Applications to Orbits, Aerospace and Virtual Reality" by J. B. Kuipers

$3.~~$ "Visualizing Quaternions" by Andrew J Hanson

$4.~~$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion and the references there in.

Comment: +1 for Kuipers - I've a read a large portion of the book and found it very clear and very useful for understanding how to use quaternions to express the orientation of one coordinate frame relative to another, and how to translate between quaternions and rotation matrices.